# Video conversion using map-reduce

Tags: ruby-on-rails, video, hadoop, ffmpeg, mapreduce

I have a Ruby on Rails application where users would be uploading videos and I'm looking for a system for converting videos uploaded by the users to `FLV` format.

Currently we are using `FFMPEG` and since video conversion is a heavy task it seems to be taking a lot of time and a lot of CPU resources..

We are looking if we can use map-reduce / Hadoop framework for implementing video conversion, as it is completely distributed.

Is it a good option to use map-reduce for video conversion in real time? If it is so, how can that be implemented?

Note: Each video file size is around 50 - 60 MB.

Answer (score 2):

Your requirement is "Real Time" conversion. Keep in mind that Hadoop is a "Batch Processing Framework".

IMHO, I say Hadoop is a poor choice here. A better solution would be definitely to use something like [Storm](http://storm.incubator.apache.org/):

> Apache Storm is a free and open source distributed realtime computation system. Storm makes it easy to reliably process unbounded streams of data, doing for realtime processing what Hadoop did for batch processing.

Personally, I implemented a project similar to yours using Storm and the result was amazing.

Another option is to use a distributed Actors model, such as Akka.io or Erlang.  But since you are a Ruby shop, Storm or Akka would be easier for your team.